# Css list with fluid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an ordered list of items.  Each ***li*** will contain a piece of text which is different in size.

I'm using bootstrap3 and I was applying the following html:

```
    <style>
        ol li:nth-child(2n+0) {
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>

    <ol class="col-lg-12" style="list-style:none;margin-left:0">
        <li class="col-lg-6">1,1</li>
        <li class="col-lg-6">1,2</li>
        <li class="col-lg-6">2,1</li>
        <li class="col-lg-6">2,2</li>  
    </ol>
```

But the result I get is this:

[image]

I'm looking to achieve this:

[image]

Has anyone managed this before with Bootstrap?

Comment: your code is not complete, please post ALL relevant code to your question

Comment: you can use [css columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) but it only works for the newer browsers, failing that, you have to use a jquery plugin for masonry